# how to append query string based on referrer using htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, iirf

Ok so i'm trying to come up with some rewrite rules in `Iirf.ini` and i can't quite get it.
I'm looking to check the referrer and then add something to the querystring of url you are hitting

1.so say i came from testing.lc and hit just the domain

```
domain.com/
```

2.or the domain with index.cfm

```
domain.com/index.cfm
```

3.or the domain with index.cfm and any number of query params

```
domain.com/index.cfm?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

4.or the domain with a shorturl

```
domain.com/login
```

5.or the domain with a shorturl and any number of query params

```
    domain.com/login?key1=value1

domain.com/page?key1=value1
```

So far i have something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://testing\.lc/.*$
RewriteRule ^/([^?]+)(\?.*|/){0,1}$ /$1?newkey=newvalue [I,QSA]
```

Which appears to work on a few urls but not all of those listed above.
This rewrite cannot use [L] either as there are other matches after for the urls such as /login that need to pass the querystring.

Any help or advice greatly appreciated...

Comment: This is quite a difficult job since you have to check first if there is a `?` or not. If it already exists you have to use `&newkey=newvalue`, if it doesn't `?newkey=newvalue` should be added ...

Comment: yea i've been trying to figure that out for a while and i'm not getting anywhere i had something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)newkey=newvalue(&|$)` but that didn't work